# cfinvokeargument with special character not working in SELECT

Tags: sql-server, coldfusion, cfinvoke

I have a cfinvoke:

```
<cfinvoke component="cfcs.people" method="getPerson">
   <cfinvokeargument name="name" value="José">
</cfinvoke>
```

And a function:

```
<cffunction name="getPerson" access="remote" returntype="any">
    <cfargument name="name" type="string">

    <cfquery name="qry" datasource="#datasource#">
        SELECT id
        FROM people
        WHERE name = <cfqueryparam value="#name#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_NVARCHAR">
    </cfquery>

    <cfreturn qry>
</cffunction>
```

I have a row in the `people` table with a `name` of "José", however the cfinvoke does not return this row. Any name that does not contain a special character works, but any name with a special character returns no rows.

**What is causing special characters to break the SELECT, and what can I do to fix it?**

Comment: What version of ColdFusion? In older versions there is a setting to enable high-ascii values for datasources.

Comment: @Miguel-F CF2018

Comment: Have you narrowed down the issue to `cfinvokeargument` and not the query itself?

Comment: What is the value of `name` within the `getPerson` function before the query is run?

Comment: @Miguel-F Yes, I tried the query in MSSQL itself, placing `'José'` in the place of `<cfqueryparam value="#name#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_NVARCHAR">` and the correct row is returned.

Comment: @Miguel-F The value appears to be `JosÃ©`

Comment: What happens if you change the `cfargument` type to "any"?

Comment: @Miguel-F The result is the same.

Comment: Alright, have you tried calling the function without using `cfinvoke`? Like `getPerson("José")` or `people.cfc?method=getPerson&name=José`

Comment: Output the literal string `José` just before the `<cfinvoke>`. Does it display as `JosÃ©`?

Comment: Yes they already confirmed that @SOS  Have you seen this before?

Comment: @Miguel-F - No, I meant without any cf code or calling any functions code. Just output the literal string. I'm guessing it's caused by the page encoding and embedding a literal unicode string, rather than a problem with cfinvoke or the function itself.

Comment: @Miguel-F Calling the function in a cfscript gives the same result.

Comment: @SOS `<cfoutput>José</cfoutput>` shows `JosÃ©`.

Comment: Ah, okay gotcha. Yes I was thinking the page encoding as well. Perhaps place the `<cfprocessingdirective pageencoding="utf-8">` tag would help here. Not sure.

Comment: @SpyderScript - Now add `<cfprocessingdirective pageencoding = "utf-8">`. It should display as `José`, and also work in the function.

Comment: @SOS That worked :)

Comment: Sweet!  @SOS go ahead and write up a proper answer.

Comment: Did you try calling it in cfscript? It would just be `person = createObject("cfcs.people").getPerson(José);`

Comment: @Redtopia makes a good point about syntax. Might consider using the sleeker `new` operator, instead of the bulkier cfinvoke. I.e. `result = new cfcs.people().getPerson(...)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try outputting *only* the literal string in a .cfm script

```
José
```

If the browser displays the mangled string below, then it is a file encoding problem, not an issue with `cfinvoke` or `cffunction`

```
JosÃ©
```

To resolve it, set the encoding to UTF-8 at the top of the script:

```
 <cfprocessingdirective pageencoding="utf-8">
```

You can also change it globally, for the entire jvm, using the jvm arg `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8`.

It's worth noting cfprocessingdirective is frequently misunderstood. The *only* reason it's required here is because the literal string `José` is embedded in the cfm source. If that string will ultimately be replaced with say a form field, then you won't need the directive. The original code will work without issue.

```
<!--- works in modern versions of CF -->
<cfinvoke component="cfcs.people" method="getPerson">
   <cfinvokeargument name="name" value="#form.name#">
</cfinvoke>
```

See also [`<cfprocessingdirective>` and how not to use it](https://blog.adamcameron.me/2013/10/cfcamp-and-how-not-to-use-it.html)